# android textView - gap beetween the text and the top TextView border

Tags: android

i want to create a TextView that the text will fill all the height.

this is my code:

```
TextView
    android:id="@+id/year"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:background="#0080f0"
    android:text="2014"/>
```

the problem is that there is a gap beetween the text and the top TextView border.

the textview is part of a caendar.

this is how the screen needs to look:

http://postimg.org/image/lprtuv355/

thanks!

Comment: Try setting `layout_height` to `wrap_content`

Comment: Try using paddingTop

Comment: setting setting layout_height to wrap_content, creates a gap on the top and bottom

Comment: using paddingTop increases top gap. iam trying to remove the gap.

Comment: Do like this `android:paddingTop=- your number`

Comment: i added android:paddingTop="-10sp".  dosent help.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the font padding. Add this to your TextView in xml:

```
android:includeFontPadding="false"
```

Comment: @ZagGol This is as close as possible to removing font padding. Can you post some pics indicating what you are after?

Comment: @ZagGol If you _absolutely_need to remove the space above (and/or below) the text, you should extend `View` and draw the text yourself. The method you would override is `onDraw(Canvas)`. Doing this will allow you to position the text as how you want.